# Padding on background image

Tags: html, css

I don't know if that is a best practice, but I used a background to put some kind of "ok icon" on a div.

My problem is that the background is setted to left and I can't put a padding there on the left side of the icon.

```
<div id="martu">
    <div class="text">
      dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#martu {
    background: url('image') no-repeat scroll 0px 8px #FFB9D9;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.text {  font-size:17px;  padding-left:20px;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9up0kmou/

PS. I know that an option would be to put the image direct on that div, but my dilema is that if background images support paddings or margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `background-position` CSS property to adjust the location of your background image on your `div`, for example:

```
#martu {
   background-position:20px 20px; // where the values are x & y coordinates from the original default position
}
```

But no, short of actually adding whitespace to the image in an image editor (not a good idea, it would add unnecessary size to the file), there's no way of adding `background-image-padding`.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9up0kmou/7/), where I have arbitrarily placed the tick icon in the middle of the element using `background-position`.

It's then a simple matter of adjusting the div padding to make sure the text doesn't overlap the image.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9up0kmou/9/) myself. Using the pseudo-elements ::before and ::after is brilliant for placing icons and other things. That way, you get clean code, and you'd need less wrapping elements.

```
#martu::before {
    content: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/2015/24x24_free_application/24/ok.png");
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/87obhb57/5/

Long story short: you can't have padding on the background image, so the trick here is to set up a `background-color` on the outer div that gives you the block appearance; setting up a `padding` on it that will provide the effect you are looking for.

```
#martu {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FFB9D9;
}
```

And finally, setting the `background-image` of the inner div to what you want plus a `padding-left` that is big enough as to ensure that the text and the image won't overlap.

```
#martu div.text {
    background-image: url('something');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    padding-left:34px;
}
```

Comment: Mhm, that is another elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks @crixi :) I saw your answer seconds before posting mine, but I thought two good ways of solving the same problem are not too many.